# .htaccess 301 redirect for all https to http EXCEPT ONE PAGE

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is the code I have currently in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I know jack about rewrites...and all of the other posts on this subject really don't fit my criteria and I don't know enough about the language to try and decipher it.

Basically what I need is this:

1. redirect all instances of "example.com" to "www.example.com"
2. redirect all instances of "**https**//www.example.com" to "**http**://www.example.com" *with the exception of 1 page*!!!! (in case it matters, the filename of that page is payments.php)

The code I have above works, but for the 1 page that I need to be https, it is rewriting the url to http.  That one page has to be https.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Thank you all for your input!

Chris

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Apache/2.2.6 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g PHP/5.2.6

I've tested it locally, all use cases seem to work fine. If you have further questions, feel free to ask.

```
# Rewrite Rules for example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect from example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL on for payments
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/payments\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but payments
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/payments\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**IMPORTANT!** When the user navigates from any *https* page with *www* to any *https* page **without** *www*, he's asked to accept security certificate of your non-www domain.

For example (YES = request to accept the certificate, NO - opposite):

```
1) https://www.asdf.com/payments.php - YES (www.asdf.com)
2) http://www.asdf.com/phpinfo.php - NO
3) https://asdf.com/phpinfo.php - YES (asdf.com)
4) https://www.asdf.com/phpinfo.php - NO
```

I tried to reorder rules in .htaccess with no success. If anyone finds a better solution, it'll be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you!  It works perfectly.  In the meantime, I'd like to read into this type of stuff a little more.  Do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: You may always read the manual ;) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 5):

in addition to william's great solution, you can negate request uri somewhere before https rewriterule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?payments\.php
```

Comment: This really is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

That was a nice post and it seems to redirect to http properly but i want some thing like the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
#RewriteRule ^products https://www.site.com/products/ [R=301,L]

# Disable SSL on pages other than payments.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^products
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Require SSL on payments.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^products\/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|static|img|payment|robots\.txt|blank.gif)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

my url is http://www.sitename.com and the trailing forward slash is optional
what i need is if there is no text like products in the url then it needs to he http://
and if there is a string products in the uri then it should be https://

how to do that...
when i tried it is going to a loop... redirection loop.

i am using codeigniter frame work and i have removed index.php from the url.

so if something like http://sitename.com/products occurred then i want it to be https://sitename.com/products

and if there no products in the url then it should redirect to http://

Answer (score -1):

```
# Rewrite Rules for example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect from example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Disable SSL on pages other than payments.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^payments\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Require SSL on payments.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^payments\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I haven't tested it but something like that should work

**Edit:** Updated

Comment: This is still allowing all other pages to be https (not rewriting them to http).

This is not rewriting http://www.example.com/payments.php to https://www.example.com/payments.php

The first redirect is still working.

I see what you're getting at.....and it looks to be right....it's just not working.  Any other ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I've tuned your code a bit. One issue is, though, that it requires to accept both example.com and www.example.com certificates.