# Apache mod_rewrite rules to disable https/ssl except for some pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I have a website that trigger HTTPS when brosing some pages and I want to revert back to HTTP when not browsing those pages, and this is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteBase /myproject/

  # toggle www prefix
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  # redirect favicon requests to the correct favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC]
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} favicon\.(ico|png|gif|jpe?g) [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite/favicon.ico [R=301,L]

  # hide index.php from root
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

  # disable HTTPS when not needed
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(https)(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/(exception|xyz|pqr)(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # otherwise forward it to index.php
  RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

If I call `https://host/url` the redirect works fine landing to `http://host/url`, but if I call `https://host/exception` instead of leaving it as is I'll be redirected to `http://host/index.php`

What's wrong? Thanks

---

**UPDATE with solution**, hoping it will be useful to someone

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteBase /yourbase

  # hide index.php from root
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

  # pass-through so when the rules loop (https), the redirect to index won't get applied
  RewriteRule index.php$ - [L]

  # toggle www prefix
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  # redirect favicon requests to the correct favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC]
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} favicon\.(ico|png|gif|jpe?g) [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://liberos.it/favicon.ico [R=301,L]

  # disable HTTPS when not needed (but don't rewrite direct files requests)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(https)(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/(yourpath|another/path)(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # if a directory or a file exists use it directly, otherwise forward it to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess 301 redirect for all https to http EXCEPT ONE PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079015/htaccess-301-redirect-for-all-https-to-http-except-one-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are routing everything through `index.php`, you need to create a pass-through so when the rules loop, the redirect won't get applied. Try adding this rule at the very top of your list of rules:

```
RewriteRule index.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this do the job! But now I have to solve the next problem: the page doesn't have full https content so the browser is displaying a warning for not safe content.
I can solve this by enabling this commented line
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(https)(.*)$
but it's not good to use referer because when I click a https link that should use http it will not match the rule and will stay https until I click on another link, then will switch to http

Comment: Note that I also had to put before your suggested rule the part to hide index.php from root, otherwise `https://host/index.php` will be reachable and I don't want

Comment: I solved also this problem and I'm posting my final htaccess hoping will help someone

Comment: Jon, Please can you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803626/how-to-route-a-particular-url-to-both-http-and-https-and-others-to-https-in-apac

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteBase /yourbase

  # hide index.php from root
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

  # pass-through so when the rules loop (https), the redirect to index won't get applied
  RewriteRule index.php$ - [L]

  # toggle www prefix
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  # redirect favicon requests to the correct favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC]
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} favicon\.(ico|png|gif|jpe?g) [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://liberos.it/favicon.ico [R=301,L]

  # disable HTTPS when not needed (but don't rewrite direct files requests)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(https)(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/(yourpath|another/path)(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # if a directory or a file exists use it directly, otherwise forward it to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```