# How to route a particular URL to both http and https and others to https in Apache httpd

Tags: apache, http, https, webserver, httpd.conf

I have a requirement to route a particular url, `/gapp` via `http and https` and other urls like `/aapp, /bapp, /capp` and the rest via `https`. I have succeded in routing everything to https but can't route `/gapp` to http. Below is my configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(gapp)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule> 

# Should mod_jk send SSL information to Tomcat (default is On)
JkExtractSSL On

# What is the indicator for SSL (default is HTTPS)
JkHTTPSIndicator HTTPS

# What is the indicator for SSL session (default is SSL_SESSION_ID)
JkSESSIONIndicator SSL_SESSION_ID

# What is the indicator for client SSL cipher suit (default is SSL_CIPHER)
JkCIPHERIndicator SSL_CIPHER

# What is the indicator for the client SSL certificated (default is SSL_CLIENT_CERT)
JkCERTSIndicator SSL_CLIENT_CERT

# Send everything for context /examples to worker named worker1 (ajp13)
# JkOptions indicates to send SSK KEY SIZE
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

# JkRequestLogFormat
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

JkMount /aapp aapp 
JkMount /bapp/* bapp

JkMount /capp capp 

JkMount /gapp gapp 
JkMount /gapp/* gapp
```

In simple words, I want to be able to do these:

```
http://example.com/gapp/
https://example.com/gapp/
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the same answer as this: [.htaccess - htaccess redirect 4 specific pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633882/htaccess-redirect-4-specific-pages-to-https)

If you want to access everything other then a few urls on https and http, you would be better not to redirect however just make a rewrite condition for the URLs and if they match then redirect them to https:

```
#force https for certain pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gapp
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```