# Redirect all but one page to http from https

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

For reasons of SEO, I would like to redirect all but one of the pages of my website from https to http. Currently, if you visit the https:// version you are presented with my website and the aforementioned prefix is in the address bar. If you visit the http:// version the https:// prefix is absent. Apparently, as a result, Google treats my site as if it were two identical sites. Not good for SEO.

St.Woland's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079015/htaccess-301-redirect-for-all-https-to-http-except-one-page) was very helpful in redirecting almost all the pages of my website from https to http. In fact, it worked like a dream until I tried visiting the one page that needed to have the secure connection.

Before trying his fix, were you to visit the secure basket page the whole page was marked as secure. However, with the recommended .htaccess fix in place, all images and css were flagged as insecure and Chrome refused to load them; the page looked a mess.

It seemed like an [article](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/force-ssl-htaccess.html) on Best Host Ratings had the solution: add further .htaccess files to the images and css folders and all would be well.

Sadly, this then meant that those pages without the https:// prefix did not load the css or the images.

Please see below the code I put in. Firstly, the .htaccess to redirect all but the basket page from https to http:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Turn SSL on for basket
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/basket\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but basket
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/basket\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Secondly, the .htaccess I placed in the images directory:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} images 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/images/$1 [R,L]
```

An obvious solution to this situation might be to just redirect the whole site across to the https version. But, placed at the base of all pages except the basket page is script from Google AdWords that places relevant ads across the internet after users have visited my site. This script is flagged as insecure.

Any help with this issue would be most appreciated.

With kind regards,

Mark

Comment: What problem are you facing with your current rules?

Comment: Hi anubhava. The problem I am having with the current rules is that I am worried about Google penalising me for having duplicate content and thus not featuring my website as high as it might be on their SERPs. Currently, there is no redirect in place from https:// to http:// I feel, were I to find a solution, I could be more confident that I had done all I could to remove duplicate content.

Comment: But your 2nd rule is already doing that `https => http` redirection.