# Disable SSL on specific WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I've spent days searching for solution. I'd like to disable SSL on one WordPress page /stream, I know it can be done via mod_rewrite but I don't know what to input there. I use Ubuntu and Apache.

EDIT: my site's redirect configuration.
EDIT2: I use pretty permalinks, so it may have a different solution than others.

> ServerName zegoattt.com
>     Redirect permanent / https://zegoattt.com/

Comment: Show us your current configuration that's doing the HTTP->HTTPS redirects.

Comment: I just edited my post.

Comment: There are so many questions on enabling/disabling ssl for specific pages, all you have to do is apply the same logic to yours. The site is not always going to have an **exact** solution for most people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess 301 redirect for all https to http EXCEPT ONE PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079015/htaccess-301-redirect-for-all-https-to-http-except-one-page)

Comment: I use WordPress and pretty permalinks, so I need to disable SSL for page /stream. So what should I put in .htaccess file in the root directory?